# Results on Maximal subgroups of $\text{GL}(n,q)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, maximal-subgroup, classical-groups

Consider, $\text{GL}(n,q)$, which is the group of $n\times n$ invertible matrices with entries from the finite fields $\mathbb{F}_q$, with $q$ elements.(We know $q$ is a prime-power). My question is really a broad one. What is known about maximal subgroups of $\text{GL}(n,q)$. By maximal subgroup, I mean the following: For a group $G$, a subgroup $H\leq G$ is maximal if there doesn't exist any proper subgroup of $G$ which properly contains $H$.

Is there any method by which one can construct maximal subgroups in $\text{GL}(n,q)$. The group $\text{SL}(n,q)$ is the subgroup of matrices with determinant 1. What are all maximal subgroups of $\text{GL}(n,q)$ containing $\text{SL}(n,q)$, and so on. Therefore, What I basically  want to know is what all is known, or if there is any very well-known result in this topic.

P.S- I searched a lot in the internet, but don't seem to find much on this or maybe there is no clear answer, I don't know. Any references will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this book has what you seek: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Subgroup-Structure-Classical-Mathematical-Society-ebook/dp/B01CEKKU8A/

Comment: Your definition of maximal subgroup is incorrect. You need to assume that $H \ne G$ (so you want $H < G$, not $H \le G$). There is a lot of literature on this, but I am afraid that it is advanced and technical. For example there is a result of Aschbacher on maximal subgroups of the finite classical groups, and also  book by Kleidman and Liebeck (mentioned by Angina Seng) on the topic which contains  much of what is known.

Comment: A newer (and I think easier to read) book on this topic is Bray/Holt/Roney-Dougal: https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Maximal_Subgroups_of_the_Low_Dimensi/9QB5AAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=The%20Maximal%20Subgroups%20of%20the%20Low-Dimensional%20Finite%20Classical%20Groups&pg=PP1&printsec=frontcover

Comment: Thank you for the references.

Answer (score 3):

The factor group ${\text GL}(n,q)/{\text SL}(n,q)$ is the cyclic group $\Bbb{F}_q^*$ of order $q-1$ because the subgroup ${\text SL} (n,q)$ is the kernel of the $\text{det}$ homomorphism.

So maximal subgroups  of ${\text GL}(n,q)$ containing $\text{SL}(n,q)$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the maximal subgroups of that cyclic group and therefore with the prime divisors of $q-1$.

**Update 1.** There are maximal subgroups which are not above $SL(n, q)$. For example, any maximal subgroup containing all upper triangular nonsingular matrices.

**Update 2.** See also [this text](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/%7Eraw/FSG/notes2.pdf), sections 5-10 for a description of maximal subgroups of ${\text GL}(n,q)$.